# Can't get Select box value in IE using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the value of a select box using JavaScript. This works in Firefox, Chrome and IE9 but not IE6,7,8. It works if i use jQuery's `val()`, but i'm trying to get the value using vanilla JavaScript. Why is this not working'.

```
$('#get').click(function() {
    var x = document.getElementById('bbb').value;//works if i do $('#bbb').val()
    alert(x)
})
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/s7YAN/25/

Comment: The reason that jQuery exists is to smooth out these type of cross-browser incompatibilities. If you want to support IE6, I'd suggest using it.

Comment: @Domenic i understand. The purpose of the question is to learn how this can be done in IE using plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Looking at the jQuery source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6/src/attributes.js#L209), you notice that for `.val()`, they get the value of `<select />` elements by getting the value of the selected `<option />` element. The code for the `<option />` value-getter is as follows:

```
function( elem ) {
    // attributes.value is undefined in Blackberry 4.7 but
    // uses .value. See #6932
    var val = elem.attributes.value;
    return !val || val.specified ? elem.value : elem.text;
}
```

So the key is that they get the option element's `text` property if the `value` one is not truthy. This is key because in your example, the `<option />` elements don't have a `value` *attribute*. So if your options were

```
<option value="xyz">xyz</option>
<option value="abcdx">abcdx</option>
```

it would work. It works in other browsers, even without the `value` attribute, because [the spec says that the `value` *property* should default to the same as the `textContent` property](http://developers.whatwg.org/the-button-element.html#the-option-element). But IE didn't implement that aspect of the spec until version 9, and only filled the `value` *property* from the `value` *attribute*.

To make your code work like you expect, without changing the markup, you should do it as in [my revised version of your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7YAN/29/):

```
$('#get').click(function() {
    var bbbEl = document.getElementById('bbb');
    var selectedOptionEl = bbbEl.options[bbbEl.selectedIndex];
    var x = selectedOptionEl.value || selectedOptionEl.text;
    alert(x);
});
```

(Note that you shouldn't use `textContent`, like the spec says, because IE6 at the very least didn't implement `textContent` at all, just `text`. So you might have a mismatch, if you rely on the difference between them, viz. that `text` is "Same as `textContent`, except that spaces are collapsed.")

Comment: The reason it fails in IE is that IE doesn't follow the [W3C HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-value-OPTION). Where an option has no value attribute, its value is the option's content.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, (assume for the code below that you put the result of getElementById into sel_node)

```
var select_data ={index:0, value:""}; 
select_data.index = sel_node.selectedIndex;
select_data.value = sel_node.options[select_data.index].value;
```

I just took this out of some old code of mine that I wrote that at the time had to work in FF or IE6. I assume this somewhat convoluted approach is what it took to work in IE6. You could probably simplify this, in my code I wanted to return the select_data object. I thought rather than rewrite it, I would just cut and paste the known working version.

(moving a comment up here for better formatting)

```
var select_node = document.getElementById('bbb');
var the_value = select_node.options[select_node.selectedIndex].value;
```

now the_value has what you want. My answer is the same as the other answer (it wasn't there when I posted or I wouldn't have bothered). All I can tell you is the code I posted is the code I used and it worked on IE6. If this doesn't work, step through with a debugger and let us know what you see for options[select_node.selectedindex]

Comment: How does this apply to my jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var list = document.getElementById('bbb');
var x = list.options[list.selectedIndex].value;
```